# Unity3d simple material color display correctly in windows built but yellow color turns to blue in android build?

Tags: unity, 3d

I have a simple roll a ball game as shown in unity 3d tutorials, and I have set the wall color as a shade of yellow using the standard shader and material. This runs flawlessly in windows application, however when running in android phone( Nexus 5 MM) the wall turns into a blue color. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any code related to this question? Or any more relevant information?

Comment: No, no code i just tried coloring the ball with a material and and dragging and dropping it to the ball, color completely changes when running in Android, for example yellow turns to shade of blue, also when i tried importing a png file of a yellow texture it turned blue, it even displays blue in the editor, not just android

Answer (score 1):

Found what was causing the problem, it was because of my dedicated graphics card! Switched over to intel and all the color related issues vanished.